# Invalid Syntax - easy_install with https://

Tags: github, ipython, easy-install

I am using IPython.

I am attempting to install a package from GitHub.

I am using the following:

```
easy_install https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/tree/master/pylearn2
```

My output states invalid syntax (highlights the "s" in https).

Specifically it states `File "<ipython-input-1-c700863fa141>", line 1`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of misunderstandings here:

1. `easy_install` is not a Python command, it is a shell command.  So you want to either run this line in a regular shell:

   ```
   $> easy_install [url]
   ```

   or prefix with `!` in IPython:

   ```
   In [1]: !easy_install [url]
   ```
2. that URL is not the right one for installing current master of a github project.  You want to use the tarball url:

   ```
   $> easy_install https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/tarball/master
   ```